# Subtracting between two ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

Is there any fast function to do the following code?

```
ArrayList<Double> A = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> B = new ArrayList<>();
//ignore adding steps
// A = [1,2,3,4,5]
// B = [0,1,2,3,4]
C = A - B
// get C = [1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? You could implement this imperatively (e.g. with for-loops) or functionally (e.g. with [Java Streams](https://oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)).

Comment: Also: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "do the following code", "ignore adding steps" and your calculation `0 = 1 - 0` i.e. `[first of C] = [first of A] - [first of B]`?

Comment: Oh, That is actually a typo. C should be `[1,1,1,1,1]`. Sorry about that. What I mean is that do we have any functions to do the same things like my code example?

Comment: Will `A` and `B` always have the same size?

Comment: Yes, `A.size()==B.size()`, always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Refer to the two complete code examples below, and their section's headings for context.

## Approaches

### Imperative approach

[*Imperative programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) is commonly described as "instructing the individual steps to achieve a certain goal".

We can use [for-loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)—a language feature [associated with imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming#Algol)—to iterate through the lists `A` and `B`, and to collect the differences of their elements in the list `C`:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ImperativeApproach {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> A = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {1d,2d,3d,4d,5d}));
    ArrayList<Double> B = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {0d,1d,2d,3d,4d}));
    
    ArrayList<Double> C = new ArrayList<>();
    
    assert A.size() == B.size();
    int size = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      C.add(A.get(i) - B.get(i));
    }
    
    System.out.println(C); // [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
  }
}
```

### Functional approach

[*Functional programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming#Functional_programming) is more declarative than imperative programming: It can be described as "requesting a certain outcome under following certain steps".

Characteristics of functional programming usually include [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) and [functions as first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)), [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509/13561410), and more.

**Aside:** Note that both *imperative* and *functional programming* are just paradigms; ways of classifying code or languages by certain "traits". Example: With the addition of [Streams](https://oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) (see below) to Java, it has become easier to write *functional code* in Java.

As mentioned before, we can make use of Java *Streams.* Example:

1. Create a stream of indices we want to access `A`/`B` at; namely, 0 to `size of A or B`.
2. [Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) the indices to the differences of the elements of `A` and `B`.
3. Collect the (streamed) result as a list named `C`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FunctionalApproach {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> A = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {1d,2d,3d,4d,5d}));
    ArrayList<Double> B = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {0d,1d,2d,3d,4d}));
    
    assert A.size() == B.size();
    int size = A.size();
    Double[] arrayC = IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToDouble((index) -> A.get(index) - B.get(index))
        .boxed()
        .toArray(Double[]::new);
    
    ArrayList<Double> C = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayC));
    
    System.out.println(C); // [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
  }
}
```

([@GrzegorzPiwowarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229438/grzegorz-piwowarek) provided [alternative and arguably better implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40696146/13561410) on [a similar but older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40644999/13561410).)

## Addendum

There may have been unfamiliar expressions in the examples above, which I'll try to explain in this section.

### Assertions

Assertions in Java are a development tool to ensure correct functionality of your code. If assertions fail, they will throw an exception. They will only run if you correctly [compile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#compiling) and [enable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable) them.

Note that **assertions do not replace proper checking!** Oracle has a [summary of when to use assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).

In the examples above I use assertions *mainly to semantically describe* that (roughly) "the following code only works under the assertion's condition".

### Primitives and boxed values

[*(Auto-)boxing* in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) refers to converting a primitive value to its corresponding wrapper class.

This is required in places where primitives cannot be used, or rather where `Object`s are expected. Examples are [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) like `List`, for which you'll find simple explanations in [Oracle's autoboxing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

**Be extra careful** if—in your code—references to such wrapper classes can be null: Java cannot unbox null to a primitive, instead **it will throw a runtime exception!** In the above code, no such scenario can occur.

#### In both approaches

Since arrays are more readable and statically compile, I chose to provide the lists' initial values as arrays. My implementation came with the following requirements:

1. Constructing `ArrayList` with initial values requires a `Collection`.<sup>[[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-)</sup>
2. `Arrays.asList()` returns a `Collection`, but requires a non-primitive array (here: array of boxed values; further: boxed array).<sup>[[2]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)</sup>
3. Initializing a boxed array (`Double[]`) requires the elements to be of the corresponding primitive type; we need to provide the numbers in type `double`.<sup>[[3]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html#:%7E:text=Passed%20as%20a%20parameter%20to%20a%20method%20that%20expects%20an%20object%20of%20the%20corresponding%20wrapper%20class.)</sup>
4. Declaring number literals as `double` requires us to suffix them with `d` (or use a decimal point).<sup>[[4]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=Floating%2DPoint%20Literals)</sup>

This means that this invalid code:

```java
ArrayList<double> A = new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Needs to be written e.g. as follows to be valid:

```java
ArrayList<Double> A = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d}));
```

#### In the imperative approach

No further code changes are required in the imperative approach's example. Adding numbers to the list `C` autoboxes the numbers, because here no intermediate object with certain restrictions like `new Double[]` is used.

#### In the functional approach

In the *Streams* example, [`IntStream.mapToDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction-) returns a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) (a stream acting on primitives). Its [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#toArray--) function would return a primitive array (`double[]`), which we cannot easily provide to the construction of the list `C` as mentioned before.

Therefore we first need to box it (see [`DoubleStream.boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#boxed--)), which returns a [`Stream<Double>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). This stream's elements can then be collected in a boxed array (by providing the array's constructor, `Double[]::new`; see [Oracle's tutorial "Method References"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)).

Such an array can then be used to construct a list as discussed before.

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through each element of both the array and subtract it from the subordinates in the other array please find the working code snippet below.

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] list1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] list2 = {0,1,2,3,4};
        int[] list3 = {0,0,0,0,0};
        
        for(int i =0; i< list1.length; i++)
        {
          list3[i] = list1[i] - list2[i];
        }
        
       for(int i =0; i< list3.length; i++)
       {
          System.out.print(list3[i]);
       }
        
    }
}
```

Which will give you the following output :

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: This is actually what I am thinking of. I just want to know do we have any built-in functions in Java to do this.

Comment: @AllonsyJia I don't think there is any built-in function to cater to this custom requirement. If this answers your question can you please mark it as correct and give it an upvote. Thanks in advance for the support given.

Comment: No, there's no "built in function".  And yes, my strong preference is exactly what Selaka Nanayakkara suggested: a "for() loop".  But  as Oskar Grosser suggested above,  [Java Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams) is also an option (for Java 8 and higher).